# Query/Join 1000+ mySQL Tables Within One Database

Tags: mysql

I want to combine and query the data from a 'large' number of tables within a database (currently increasing, but sitting over the 1000 mark). Not every table has exactly the same columns, but they share a core.

Is there a way I can go about this without some sort of massive `JOIN` command? The ideal output would include every column that is currently in any single table, blank for any row whose table doesn't include that column.

Comment: Sounds like you have a really bad table design. Why so many tables need to be joined?

Comment: Does anyone on StackOverflow ever answer the question that is actually asked?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `union all`, not a `join`:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, . . . , NULL as coln
from table1 t1 union all
select t2.col1, NULL as col2, . . . t2.coln
from table t2 union all
. . .
```

You have to list all the columns for all the tables.  You can use a spreadsheet to generate the code.  Or, you can pull the columns from `information_schema.columns` to arrange the `union`s.

You may start hitting limits in MySQL when using thousands of tables.  It sounds like a really bad idea to have so many similar tables in your database.  You may want to revisit your data model.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'm still struggling with this though. Each table has up to 100 columns, and I'm certainly not typing them all out!